# Ansible pamd: module failure

Tags: ansible, rhel7

i have this playbook as a part of a role that do some changes in pam modules :

```
---

- name: "{{ BANNER}} - SET MODE"
  copy:
    remote_src: True
    src: "{{ LOGIN_DEF }}"
    dest: "{{ LOGIN_DEF_BCK }}_RH7-021_{{ CK_ORA }}"

  replace:
    path: "{{ LOGIN_DEF }}"
    regexp: '{{ item.src }}'
    replace: '{{ item.dst }}'
  with_items:
    - { src: '(.*FAIL_DELAY.*)', dst: '#\1' }

  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ LOGIN_DEF }}"
    line: 'FAIL_DELAY 10'

  replace:
    path: "{{ PASSWORDAUTH }}"
    regexp: '{{ item.src }}'
    replace: '{{ item.dst }}'
  with_items:
    - { src: '^auth .* pam_faildelay.so', dst: '' }

  pamd:
    name: password-auth
    type: auth
    control: sufficient
    module_path: 'pam_unix.so'
    new_type: auth
    new_control: optional
    new_module_path: 'pam_faildelay.so'
    module_arguments:
    state: after

  replace:
    path: "{{ SYSTEMAUTH }}"
    regexp: '{{ item.src }}'
    replace: '{{ item.dst }}'
  with_items:
    - { src: '^auth .* pam_faildelay.so', dst: '' }

  pamd:
    name: system-auth
    type: auth
    control: sufficient
    module_path: 'pam_unix.so'
    new_type: auth
    new_control: optional
    new_module_path: 'pam_faildelay.so'
    module_arguments:
    state: after

  debug: msg="{{ MSG_SET }}"
```

When i run i have this error :

```
TASK [RH7-021 : pamd] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.13.203.165]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  
File \"/home/ccansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1561986679.75-245340126875212/AnsiballZ_pamd.py\", line 113, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  
File \"/home/ccansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1561986679.75-245340126875212/AnsiballZ_pamd.py\", line 105, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  
File \"/home/ccansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1561986679.75-245340126875212/AnsiballZ_pamd.py\", line 48, in invoke_module\r\n    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\r\n  
File \"/tmp/ansible_pamd_payload_NpycuP/__main__.py\", line 880, in <module>\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_pamd_payload_NpycuP/__main__.py\", line 816, in main\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_pamd_payload_NpycuP/__main__.py\", line 458, in __init__\r\n  
File \"/tmp/ansible_pamd_payload_NpycuP/__main__.py\", line 371, in rule_from_string\r\n
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'\r\n", 
"msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/PG005856/HARDENING/main.retry
```

I can't figure it out what's wrong morover i used the same method on other playbook at it worked fine.

The control node has this ansible version :

```
ansible 2.7.6
  config file = /home/PG005856/HARDENING/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/PG005856/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /ansible/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /ansible/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Feb 20 2018, 09:19:12) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)]
```

Thr target server is :

```
    Linux rh7-test-ansible 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jan 14 10:36:03 EST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
   cat /etc/redhat-release
    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
```

I have read that was a bug but i could imagined that with ansible version 2.7 was resolved.

I don't know what to do i could archieve the same result with some lines of sed with shell module but i'd like to use the pamd: module.

Comment: looks like this : https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/53786
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`
you can aply the patch line 455 in pamd.py temporarily, and wait for update with this ticket closed.

 You can help yourself by looking at open bugs on github, have a nice day

Comment: Thank you for your help it was really this bug! Thomas

Comment: it was a pleasure to help, does the patch do the trick for you?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly! next time i'm going to look at open bugs ! :)